# Etimologia da palavra "racismo"

Tags: significado, etimologia, neologismos

Assumindo que pertencemos à raça humana, me parece errado usar a palavra "racismo" para descrever o preconceito. 
Como o preconceito ocorre devido a etnia, o correto não seria "etinismo"?

Entendo também que o julgamento popular dá o significado à palavra.

Comment: A [resposta do Victor](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/613/156) deu uma boa explicação. Noto apenas que a palavra "_etinismo_" não existe, mas [_etnicismo_](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/etnicismo) existe, significando _paganismo_. Para além disto a palavra [_raça_](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/ra%C3%A7a) é utilizada para classificar subdivisão de animais, daí usarem-se as expressões "raça branca", "raça negra", "raça vermelha", etc. [_Etnia_](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/etnia), por outro lado, é usada para classificar "agrupamento de famílias numa área geográfica" por conjunto de fatores.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

De acordo com a [definição da wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racism#Etymology), isso começou porque no século XIX alguns cientistas defendiam que a população era dividida em raças e que algumas raças são superiores a outras.

O termo "racismo" surgiu só nos anos 1930, e é uma simplificação do termo mais antigo "racialismo" que existe ao menos desde a primeira década do século XX, mas caiu em desuso depois que o termo "racismo" surgiu. Inicialmente, esta palavra significava apenas uma ação motivada pela raça de uma pessoa, sem que tivesse significado positivo ou negativo (da mesma forma que podemos ter ação motivada pelo gênero, cor dos olhos, estatura, ou qualquer outra característica física).

Entretanto, o termo "racismo" rapidamente ganhou uma conotação negativa, exatamente porque a maioria das ações motivadas por raça implica em algo que prejudique um grupo ao mesmo tempo que privilegia outro, usando como critério a cor da pele. Assim, o termo rapidamente passou a ser designado como "discriminação racial" ou "ódio racial".

Acontece que hoje em dia, a maioria dos biólogos e antropólogos rejeitam a divisão por raças, preferindo critérios como etnia. Então ocorre que o termo fazia sentido quando definido originalmente, aonde admitia-se que a população humana era dividida em raças. A noção de raças foi abandonada, mas o termo ficou.

Observe que o termo "racismo", de acordo com a conotação moderna, se refere à preconceito ou ódio motivado por raça, mas sem especificar qual raça é privilegiada ou qual é prejudicada. Historcamente, a raça negra é a que tem sido a mais prejudicada, mas o termo também serve para discriminação contra índios, mestiços, orientais e até mesmo contra brancos.

Algo diferente ocorre com a palavra "machismo" que designa a discriminação especificamente contra mulher em benefício do homem, e não apenas a "discriminação motivada por gênero". Para as coisas ficarem etimologicamente confusas, a palavra "feminismo" significa igualdade entre gêneros e combate ao machismo. Por causa disso, a palavra "[femismo](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/femismo/)" foi cunhada para denotar a discriminação contra o homem em benefício da mulher, mas tal palavra não é amplamente usada.

Ou seja, tudo depende do contexto histórico no qual a palavra surge, mesmo que ao longo dos anos ela acabe se desviando do significado ou contexto original ou ganhando conotações tendenciosas, tais como "racismo". Além disso, se você confrontar o significado destas palavras com o substantivo primitivo que a origina, verá que as derivações têm significado bem incoerentes e assimétricos em relações umas as outras ("macho -> machismo" e "fêmea -> feminismo").

Comment: muito bem respondido! E vc já respondeu a minha próxima pergunta, que seria sobre o "feminismo"! :D

Answer (score -1):

Como você disse, pertencemos à raça humana. Mas o mesmo é referido à qualquer raça, como câes - pastor alemão, husky siberiano, e até vira-lata - e todos os outros animais. O ser humano também tem suas raças: negra, branca, amarela, pardo e indígena. E, pelo menos no Brasil, a questão é realmente gerada em torno da raça e, infelizmente em razão de sua elite. Pois eu mesmo acredito que os benefícios - principalmente ao negro e indígena nas faculdades - pra mim, é um tipo de racismo contra brancos, pardos e amarelos. Eu acredito que esse tipo de benefício deveria ser baseada na classe social, pois do mesmo jeito que há negros pobres, também há negros ricos, estudantes de escolas maravilhosas; e brancos pobres que não têm onde morar. Claro que o percentual pode ser bem diferente, mas ainda acredito que esses benefícios deveriam basear-se em classe social.

Comment: Olá @Juliana, gosto deste post mas é desejável que respostas sobre Etimologia incluam referências a fontes documentais. Recomendo que considere (entre outros possiveis) o dicionário Etimológico do Antenor Nascentes, pode encontrar o livro seguindo uma ligação [neste post](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/331/4645). Pedia-lhe a gentileza de editar a pergunta e incluir um citação do autor sobre o verbete, pois enriquece a resposta para os leitores e membros da comunidade. Obrigado.

Comment: Juliana, deixo-lhe também aqui este [exemplo de um post](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/7663) que segue uma formatação e abordagem aos conteúdos muito bons. Foi escrito pelo @Jacinto que é um distinto membro desta comunidade e nos mostra por seus exemplos como se escrevem artigos de muito elevada qualidade. Espero que goste e seja útil às suas contribuições.