# Uso histórico da palavra "distopia"?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, origem-histórica, palavra-para-ideia

Em conversa com um amigo surgiu a pergunta: A palavra "distopia" existe em Português? [Segundo o priberam existe](https://dicionario.priberam.org/distopia).

O verbete do priberam também indica um termo homónimo da medicina e, por outro lado, como antônimo de "útopia" (que -para minha surpresa- é uma palavra forjada recentemente por [São Thomas More](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_More)).

O uso de "distopia" é frequente na produção cultural anglófona. Gostava de saber quando esta acepção do vocábulo entrou na língua Portuguesa?

Comment: Recentemente há coisas de 500 anos...  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Distopia*** na aceção médica ’localização anormal de um órgão’ aparece já em 1913 no [dicionário de Cândido Figueiredo](https://archive.org/details/dicionario-aberto.net/page/n687/mode/2up/search/distopia?q=%22situa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20n%C3%B3mala%22); na aceção ’lugar imaginário ruim’, só encontrei a partir de 1958. O dicionário Houaiss, o melhor que eu conheço em matéria de etimologia, só traz a aceção médica, e só a atesta em 1926.

Isto é paralelo à evolução do inglês *dystopia*, em que a palavra portuguesa certamente se inspira. Segundo o [Etymoline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=dystopia), o inglês *dystopia* está atestado na aceção médica em 1844, e em 1952 na aceção ’lugar imaginário ruim’;  mas havia nesta aceção o adjetivo *dystopian* já em 1868. A palavra foi formada a partir prefixo de origem grega *dys-*, *dis-* no português atual, ’mau, anormal’; e *-topia* de *utopia*, do grego *tópos*, ’lugar’. Portanto, literalmente ’lugar anormal (para o órgão)’ e ’lugar ruim’.

### Localização anormal

Depois do dicionário de Cândido de Figueiredo de 1913 ([*distopia*](https://archive.org/details/dicionario-aberto.net/page/n687/mode/2up/search/distopia?q=%22situa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20n%C3%B3mala%22) e [*dystopia*](https://archive.org/details/dicionario-aberto.net/page/n705/mode/2up/search/dystopia?q=%22situa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20n%C3%B3mala%22); 2ª edição; na 1ª, 1899, não vem), encontrei o adjetivo em 1916 e o substantivo em 1920 (grafia original, negrito meu em todas as citações):

> Minuciosa exploração determinou que tal tumor era constituido por um orgam **dystopico**, — o rim direito
>   [Dr. Rocha Vaz, “A dôr nas desordens renaes”, *Brazil-Medico*, Rio de Janeiro, 9-9-1916](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=081272x&pesq=dystopico&pasta=ano%20191)
>
> Dentre essas [condições pathologicas] ressaltam em primeiro plano: a ulcera duodenal, a cholelithiase chronica, os processos appendiculares, as enterites e a **dystopia** renal.
>   [Dr. Rocha Vaz, “Dores Gastricas”, *Brazil-Medico*, Rio de Janeiro, 20-3-1920](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=081272x&pesq=dystopia&pasta=ano%20192)

Este uso encontra-se com frequência a partir de então no [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=distopia&lr=lang_pt&tbs=lr:lang_1pt,sbd:1,cdr:1,cd_max:1960&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk00ghdB_Ij75H1nG5KCkQe8O4arECA:1586018794226&ei=6rmIXqavDYnQadfigcAM&start=20&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwimzNi2nM_oAhUJaBoKHVdxAMgQ8tMDCOcB&biw=1366&bih=625&dpr=1) e na [Hemeroteca Digital Brasileira](http://memoria.bn.br/hdb/periodico.aspx). Nas décadas de 1930 e 1940 são frequentes as grafias *distopia* e *dystopia*. A distopia do rim parece ser de longe a mais comum.

### Lugar imaginário ruim

O exemplo mais antigo que encontrei, seis anos depois de a palavra estar atestada em inglês, foi num comentário sobre Zé Fernandes, personagem-narrador de *A Cidade e as Serras* (1901) de Eça de Queiroz; o autor inclui uma explicação de *distopia* entre parênteses, o que sugere que ele não esperava que os leitores conhecessem o termo:

> Para Zé Fernandes, pelo contrário a Cidade nunca poderá dar trânsito a qualquer Eutopia, mas sim ao mesmo tipo de **Distopia** (lugar não agradável) em que se tornarão no século XX as cidades fabulosas e kafkianas da *science fiction* [p.54]
>   [...]
>   A capital francesa, na última visão que dela nos dá Zé Fernandes (capítulo XVI e último do livro), transformara-se de vez na **Distopia** da ficção científica. [p. 68]
>   [Alexandre Pinheiro Torres, *Ensaios escolhidos: estudos sobre as literaturas de língua portuguesa*, v. 1, 1958](https://books.google.pt/books?id=itAQAQAAMAAJ&q=distopia&dq=distopia&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiap9yvgc3oAhUG3xoKHaYEDJ8Q6AEIMjAB)

Na [*Cidade e as Serras*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Cidade_e_as_Serras), o protagonista, um homónimo meu, começa por ser um parisiense apaixonado por todas as modernices, para depois se render aos encantos da vida simples lá para as serranias do Douro. Já no exemplo seguinte, uma década mais tarde, *distopia* refere-se a sociedades totalitárias, com um controle do governo sobre o indivíduo para lá dos sonhos de Mao Tsé-Tung, tais como imaginadas por Aldous Huxley em [*Admirável Mundo Novo*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admir%C3%A1vel_Mundo_Novo) (1932) e George Orwell em [*1984*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/1984_(livro)) (1948):

> Na **distopia** que Huxley publicou em 1932 [p. 70]
>   [...]
>   […] a **distopia** “My” do escritor russo Eugênio Zamyatin, frequentemente apontada como fonte de Brave New World e 1984. [p. 155]
>   [*Estudos anglo-hipânicos*, 1968](https://books.google.pt/books?id=c_gSAAAAYAAJ&q=distopia&dq=distopia&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIpIbTic_oAhUxC2MBHUiCD0MQ6AEIjgEwCw)

Vão-se continuando a encontrar exemplos no Google Books, e o uso explode já neste século.

Answer (score 0):

Citando a [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distopia):

> Distopia ou antiutopia é qualquer representação ou descrição organizacional cujo valor representa a antítese da utopia ou promove a vivência em uma "utopia negativa"[1](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distopia)[2]. O termo também pode referir-se a um lugar ou estado imaginário em que se vive sob condições de extrema opressão, desespero ou privação. As distopias são geralmente caracterizadas pelo totalitarismo, autoritarismo, pelo controle opressivo sobre toda a sociedade. A tecnologia é usada como ferramenta de controle, seja por parte do estado, seja de instituições ou mesmo de corporações.[3]
>
> Distopias são frequentemente criadas como avisos ou como sátiras, mostrando as atuais convenções sociais e limites extrapolados ao máximo. Uma distopia está intimamente conectada à sociedade atual. Nesse aspecto, distopias diferem fundamentalmente das utopias, que são sistemas sociais idealizados e sem raízes na sociedade atual, figurando em outra época ou tempo ou após uma grande descontinuidade histórica. Um número considerável de histórias do subgênero cyberpunk de ficção científica, ambientadas num futuro mais ou menos próximo, usam padrões distópicos em que uma empresa de alta tecnologia domina um mundo em que os estados nacionais se tornaram fracos.
>
> Na literatura, famosas distopias foram concebidas por George Orwell (1903-1950) e Aldous Huxley (1894-1963).[

Comment: Bem vindo ao SO-PT. Vi que a sua resposta contém números de referências. Se copiou da wikipedia devia editar para indicar a proveniência do texto. É norma não serem permitidas transcrições completas sem indicação de proveniência por constituir pelâgio. Acrescentava valor se escrevesse um texto seu -que é muito bem vindo- incluíndo citações do artigo da wiki a seu gosto. A pergunta inicial era sobre a origem e história da palavra na língua Portuguesa, pode reparar que o artigo do @Jacinto nessa perspecriva até supera o artigo da wikipedia.

Comment: Luander, editei para deixar claro que é uma citação, seguindo a conclusão [desta discussão no meta](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258/good-practice-in-posts-that-just-copy-paste-other-sites). Para citar um texto em bloco, barra vertical cinzenta, como eu fiz, começa o parágrafo com o sinal >. Se clicares em "edit" no canto inferior esquerdo, podes ver como eu fiz.  E subscrevo o que o @bad_coder disse acima: acrescentas valor se juntares pensamento teu. Já vi respostas que são praticamente só citação mas que respondem diretamente à pergunta; esta não é uma delas.